# Loading url link when click over accordion tabs into the iframe

Tags: jquery, url, iframe, accordion

The following script will show you a jquery accordion tabs with iframe and link beside each h3. I want when I click over the h3 link, the link load the url into the iframe? As simple as that

I tried many hours to solve this issue but I could not.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Rig Counts</title>
<script src="../java/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
<script src="../java/jquery-ui.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
<script type="text/jscript">  
$(function() {    
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({     
collapsible: true,
active : false,
});  
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="accordion" style="width: 441px; height: 1565px;">

    <h3><a href="http://www.example.com" target="I1">test1</a></h3>
    <div style="width: 400px; height: 500px">
        <iframe id="I1" border="0" frameborder="0" name="I1" scrolling="auto" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
        </iframe>
    </div>

    <h3><a href="http://www.example.com" target="I2">test2</a></h3>
    <div>
        <div style="width: 238px; height: 270px;">
            <iframe id="I2" border="0" frameborder="0" name="I2" scrolling="no" src="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/om1sL4cz/)

Comment: Your code seems to work. The 2nd link has a wrong "target" btw

Comment: no, it does not work. Yes, it works if I remove the accordion script. but once I put the accordion script, suddenly it does not work!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using a link to add the `src` as if you know the url to put into the href you shold be able to use it directly in the src of the iframe.  But anyway here is the answer to your problem using the jQuery:

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({     
    collapsible: true,
    active : false,
    beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {
        $(ui.newPanel).find('iframe').attr('src', $(ui.newHeader).find('a:eq(0)').attr('href'));
    }
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pnfajexy/)

[More information about the beforeActivate event](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-beforeActivate)

Comment: this solution is what I need. let me test it and I will get back to you. appreciate your kindly help...

Comment: thank you very much for your help. yes this is what I need. but another minor problem in your code. Your solutions is working fine in the (jsfiddle), but when I test it in the IE 9, for some reason it breaks the accordion tabs. I don't know why

Comment: This solution solved my issue. many thanks... just one note that the script (jquery script) should be post after the accordion tags in the html body section.

Comment: @Khalil sorry, did you solve your ie9 problem - I'm just in the process of putting a site live and am very busy at the moment so haven't been able to look at it.  Also your other comment, if you run the above script within the `$(function() {});`, like in your example code above, it should work whereever you put it.  It is like the jsfiddle's onload option (which is why I removed it from the fiddle)

Comment: Many thanks Pete. every things goes fine with me, and your cooperation is highly appreciated. your secript goes fine. one more thing, what book should I read to be professional like you in coding :)

Comment: I just use the internet - whenever I get stuck I usually look at the api or online manual for the language I am working on or ask a question on here!